# submit form and then show results in an existing div

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

This don't work for me. The results show in action form page.

jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#em2").submit(function() { 
        $.ajax({ 
            data: $(this).serialize(), 
            type: $(this).attr('method'), 
            url: $(this).attr('action'), 
            success: function(response) { 
                $('#resultados').html(response); 
            }
        });
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('#resultados').offset().top -292 
        }, 'slow');
        return false; 
    });
});
</script>
```

html:

```
<form id="em2" name="em2" action="resultados.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="e" value="No" />
    <input type="hidden" name="b" value="empleo" />
    <input type="hidden" name="q" value="02" />
</form>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:document.forms['em2'].submit();return false;">Ver</a>
    .
    .
    .
<div id="resultados">

</div>
```

By submitting the form the results show in new window (resultados.php).

I don't understand why.

Comment: Have you tried to replace action="resultados.php" with action=""?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your trigger is the problem; rather than triggering the `submit` event, the following line is simply submitting the form by default action. To actually trigger the `submit` event your would need a `submit` button or use jQuery to trigger the event using any of these forms: `$('#em2').submit(), $('#em2').trigger('submit')`:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:document.forms['em2'].submit();return false;">Ver</a>
```

Either change it to the following as in [this working example](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/3ARuh/):

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:$('#em2').submit();return false;">Ver</a>
```

Or try to avoid inline js and do the following (recommended):

```
<a id='theTrigger' href='#'>Ver</a>

$(function() {
    $('#theTrigger').on( 'click',  function() {
        $('#em2').submit();
    });
});
```

Which effectively changes your code to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#theTrigger').on( 'click',  function() {
        $('#em2').submit();
    });    
    $("#em2").submit(function() { 
        $.ajax({ 
            data: $(this).serialize(), 
            type: $(this).attr('method'), 
            url: $(this).attr('action'), 
            success: function(response) { 
                $('#resultados').html(response); 
            }
        });
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('#resultados').offset().top -292 
        }, 'slow');
        return false; 
    });
});
```

Comment: This work fine but the results show now utf8 encoded and if an input contain a non standard character doesn't show results.

Comment: Solved. I have added `mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");` in resultados.php

Comment: Glad it worked for you and thanks for the feedback. Please let us know if you have any questions and feel free to accept this as the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The default behaviour for form elements is to show the page that you put in the "action"-attribute.

You can fix this by changing this line of your jQuery code...

```
$("#em2").submit(function() { 
    $.ajax({
```

... to this:

```
$("#em2").submit(function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
```

This way, you can prevent the default HTML-form behaviour!

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` is equivalent to `return false` that he already has. This does not work; I already tried it.